Dirichlet's series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Furthermore, suppose that exists some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^{z_0}}$ converges.

Now, my goal is to prove the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{z}}$ with $Re(z)>Re(z_0)$.
By summation by parts, ($A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n}{n^{z-z_0}}$):
\begin{align*} \tiny
&\sum_{n=l}^{m} \frac{a_n}{n^{z}} \\  
=\sum_{n=l}^{m}A_{n}(n^{-(z-z_0)}-(n+1)^{-(z-z_0)})+  \\ A_{n-1}((m+1)^{-(z-z_0)}-l^{-(z-z_0)})+&(A_{m}-A_{n-1})(m+1)^{-(z-z_0)}
\end{align*}
And by MVT,
$$|n^{-(z-z_0)}-(n+1)^{-(z-z_0)}| \leq \frac{|z-z_0|}{c^{Re(z-z_0)+1}} \leq \frac{|z-z_0|}{n^{Re(z-z_0)+1}}  c \in [n;n+1]$$
And as $Re(z-z_0)+1>1$, $(n^{-(z-z_0)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is of bounded variation and as it converges to $0$, by Dirichlet's test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{z}}$ converges.
Is it OK?

One basic issue: do you mean absolute convergence? ... otherwise, it's pretty hard to deduce further things... Clarify?

@paulgarrett No, it is usual convergence. The corresponding result for absolute convergence is also true, and pretty much trivial. However, for Dirichlet series we also have this pretty surprising result for convergence in general. I don't really remember the details of the proof though. (read it some time ago in Apostol's analytic number theory book)
